# How to Show Substitute Text for Some Values in NumericUpDown?

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I made a dialog box that contains a numericupdown control, which has a range of -1~100

I want to show "infinite" for -1 instead of the raw value.

Comment: isnt it possible to check if number == -1 and show the text infinite else show the actual number in the text box of the numeric updown control ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired behaviour you have to create your own control that inherits from `NumericUpDown`. To change the text you can override the [`UpdateEditText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.updateedittext.aspx) method:

```
public class NumericUpDownEx : NumericUpDown
{
    public NumericUpDownEx()
    {
    }

    protected override void UpdateEditText()
    {
        if (Value < 0)
        {
            Text = "infinite";
        }
        else
        {
            base.UpdateEditText();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Text doesn't seem to be a member of NumericUpDown.

Comment: It is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs40s7ds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. But you can not just set its value like you would do in a text box.

Comment: Interesting. Intellisense doesn't show Text property but your code compiles well. Now I see the point of "not intended to be used directly from your code." from MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not %100 sure but [`NumericUpDownAccelerationCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdownaccelerationcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class looks good for you.

> Represents a sorted collection of NumericUpDownAcceleration objects in
>   the NumericUpDown control.

Maybe something like;

```
NumericUpDown1.Accelerations.Items[0].Value = -1;
NumericUpDown1.Accelerations.Items[0].Text = "infinite";
```

Comment: `NumericUpDownAcceleration` objects describe how fast the value changes when you keep pressing the buttons (i.e. after 1 second use increment 5, after 2 seconds use increment 10).